# Issues with diff(f,x,n) in MacLaurin series

Tags: matlab, function, differentiation

We had an assignment asking us to estimate `exp(2)` using  *MacLaurin series* and I've taken it a bit further trying to develop and function where you can input an equation, the value of `x` you wish to estimate and to how many significant figures you want to have it.

It works well for certain equations, i.e. `exp(x)`, `sin(x)`, even `exp(x) + 2x`, but the second I throw in an higher power on `x`, say `x^2` it returns `0`.

For example, when I call the function as: `MacLaurin(x^2,2,1)` , it returns `0` which is not a proper answer.

Here is the code:

```
% Created by: DarkRiot43
% Student #: 
% Date: Sept 12, 2016
% Course: Numerical Analysis, MTH 510

function [  ] = MacLaurin( func , valueOfx, sigfigs )
%MACLAURIN Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
%       inputs: func: a function
%               sigfigs: the number of significant figures you would like
%               to have the answer evaluated to.
clc;
syms f(x) x ;
f(x) = func;
presentApprox = 0;
previousApprox = 0;
n = 0;
% Find the criterion for stopping the iteration as an double not a percent.
Es = (0.5*10^(2-round(sigfigs)))/100;   

Ea =Es+1; % Ensures Ea is larger than Es to begin

while Ea >= Es
    %differentiate the n'th derivative of the equation f(x) w.r.t. x
    beenDiff = diff(f(x),n); 
    presentApprox = previousApprox + (vpa(subs(beenDiff,x,0))* (((valueOfx)^n)/factorial(n))); %MacLaurin series structure used to evaluate.
    n = n+1; %Counter incrementation
  % Call to function    approxError to determine approximate relative error.
    Ea = approxError(presentApprox,previousApprox); 
    previousApprox = presentApprox; 
    f(x) = beenDiff;      
    % can be used to ensure proper iterating counting of the program
    disp(n); 

    disp(f(x)); %shows the n'th derivative function

    %check to see if in the approxError function there would have been a
    %by zero error. if so I edit the value (999 was all i could think of?
    % was thinking of using something else but didn't know what to use
    if Ea == 999
        break;
    end
end
else
    fprintf('\nStopping criterion used:\t');
    disp(Es*100)


    fprintf('The estimate generated using MacLaurin Series of ');
    disp(func);
    fprintf('using the value x = %.3f is: \n\n',valueOfx);
    fprintf('%7f',presentApprox);
    fprintf('\nThis was done using %d iterations', n);

    if Ea == 0
        fprintf('\nCould not reach the requested stopping criterion.');

    end


end 

function [Ea] = approxError(presentApprox,previousApprox) 
%Approximate relative error Function
% inputs:
%   presentApprox: type double
%   previousApprox: type double
% returns: 
%   Ea: type double
%       
%   Uses two values to determine the approximate relative error w.r.t
%       eachother

    if presentApprox ~= 0

        Ea = (presentApprox - previousApprox)/(presentApprox);

    elseif presentApprox == 0

        disp('Cannot determine the value with more precision as it would   involve dividing by zero!');
        Ea = 999;

    end 
end
```

Please ask if I have been unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code (other than the syntactic error at the end of the while loop which I've edited).  The first is the line where f(x) = beenDiff.  beenDiff is supposed to be the n'th derivative, so if you make this assignment, diff actually becomes the (n!)th derivative.  Removing the line f(x)=beenDiff sorts out this issue.

The second issue is that your stopping criteria isn't good - if any of the derivative functions happen to produce 0, then the code will simply stop as the difference is zero, regardless of whether further iterations would alter the value.  For something like cosine, this is a problem.  (The code will refuse to run if the function itself produces a zero at x=0, so sin(x) simply doesn't work).

Getting the stopping criterion right is quite a challenge in itself as you need to know the magnitude of later derivatives of the function in order to ensure that you don't get larger jumps.  (A function may converge, but it doesn't have to monotonically converge on every iteration).

Comment: Thank you Dave,
I'll look into those issues. As I thought, I seem to be in over my head. That being said, it was a nice challenge to get where I am  currently.